# Drag and drop lagging

Tags: javascript

As part of a school project, I have DIVs that I need to be able to move. I have it working, and it works perfectly in Firefox. However, in other browsers, it doesn't really work that well. In IE9, it doesn't work at all. In Safari, it lags, even when only one div is up. In Opera and Chrome, it works fine when there's only one div, but if there are several divs on top of each other, and I try to move one over the others, it lags.

I've been going at it for a while, and I've really run out of ideas as to what could cause it.

As this is for school, we're not allowed to use any libraries (as this would have simplified it quite a bit).

The code for making divs draggable is here: http://pastebin.com/4TGRg1AW

Comment: would you mind making a http://jsfiddle.net/ out of it instead of the pastebin?

Comment: I don't know what the problem is, but I just wanted to say nice job so far. That is some of the most tidy and well organised homework code that I've seen on SO, so kudos for that even if it doesn't work.

Comment: I'm afraid I've never actually used jsfiddle, so not really sure how much I'm supposed to put in there.

Answer (score 0):

Are you not allowed to use something like jQuery?  It takes care of a lot of js browser compatibility issues.

Comment: We're not allowed to use anything but jQuery Core, and I don't really think that would help me with this.

Comment: I was thinking, depending on the nature of your errors, it might help with some of the browser incompatibilities in working with elements and events.  Are you able to capture any errors coming from the browsers?

Comment: No, no errors occur. Besides, IE is the only one that actually doesn't work. The others work, just as Firefox, it's just that they lag.