# Why is HTML5 Drag and Drop so slow compared to mouse event

Tags: javascript, html

I wanted to implement a draggable window in Angular 2, and I first tried this in [a codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QpZJJJ).

However, even using plain JavaScript, it seems to be very slow, compared to the plain old mouse event counterpart which are used everywhere.

My example is tested on Safari, I knew that the example doesn't work in Chrome/Firefox, I think Chrome fires an additional bad `drag` and Firefox doesn't expose mouse position in `drag` event.

Also, the example works much better in Chrome, producing zero to no lag. I found a [reference on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8596165/drag-and-drop-lagging) saying Safari is the only one that lags.

```
"use strict"
let el = document.getElementById("window")
let anchor = { x: 0, y: 0 }
let begin = { x: 0, y: 0 }
let newPosition = { x: 0, y: 0 }
let needsRedraw = false

let use = "drag"

if (use == "drag") {
  el.draggable = "true"
  el.addEventListener('dragstart', event => {
    begin = { x: Number.parseInt(el.style.left),
              y: Number.parseInt(el.style.top) }
    anchor = { x: event.clientX, y: event.clientY }
  })
  document.addEventListener('drag', event => {
    let dx = event.clientX - anchor.x
    let dy = event.clientY - anchor.y
    newPosition = { x: begin.x + dx, y: begin.y + dy }

    needsRedraw = true
  })
} else if (use == "click") {
  let moving = false
  el.addEventListener('mousedown', event => {
    moving = true
    begin = { x: Number.parseInt(el.style.left),
              y: Number.parseInt(el.style.top) }
    anchor = { x: event.clientX, y: event.clientY }
  })
  document.addEventListener('mousemove', event => {
    if (moving) {
      let dx = event.clientX - anchor.x
      let dy = event.clientY - anchor.y
      newPosition = { x: begin.x + dx, y: begin.y + dy }
      needsRedraw = true
    }
  })
  document.addEventListener('mouseup', event => {
    moving = false
  })
}

function draw() {
  requestAnimationFrame(draw)
  if (needsRedraw) {
    el.style.left = newPosition.x + "px"
    el.style.top = newPosition.y + "px"
    needsRedraw = false
  }
}

requestAnimationFrame(draw)
```

Comment: Which browsers?

Comment: added in the question, i tested mainly in Safari, so the example doesn't work perfectly in Chrome, the performance in Chrome is substantially better.

Answer (score 0):

Testing with just Angular 2, I used direct element access through `ElementRef` to minimize performance impact.

Chrome did work a lot better, with or without `requestAnimationFrame`. However, if I close Safari's Developer Console, everything seems to work smoothly enough.

Discovering that, all seems to be a non-issue. (Also throttling `dragover`/`drag` events doesn't improve performance since the biggest performance impact is on DOM change and the browser had to redraw the element)